# Doube hung window leaks

Tags: windows

[image]window leaks over the 1-inch lip of the front of the rail into the house during heavy rains, the back lip is only 1/2 inch. You would think the rising water in the rail channel would just flow over the shorter back lip? The water flows into the holes on each side of the rail and flows out the two weep holes in the back of the window. No problem with my other 22 windows just with 4 that overflow.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foGAH.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foGAH.jpg)

Comment: It would be better to edit your question of a few hours ago rather than post another same question. And still, the water is not able to exit the weep holes fast enough during a strong rain. You say you cleaned the weep holes- it is possible the channel under the  bottom "rail" as you call it, is blocked with 25 years of accumulated dust and debris so the weep hole exits are compromised and not functioning to their fullest extent. Hence the issue of the weep holes functioning with light rain but being not functional in heavy rain.

Comment: HI Kyle, I LOVE your clear, concise advice.  I incorrectly called the pocket sill a bottom track or rail. A window repairman recommended two holes in the back lip of pocket sill.

Comment: HI Kyle,  The pocket sill cannot be popped out, so I will attempt to place a narrow nozzle, attached to my garden hose, into the side holes of the sill pocket and gently wash out the remaining debris in the chamber. If an extra weep hole is still needed a could use a Dremel to carve out a new weep hole and add a weep hole cover with a hinge. Is there a way I could also test whether the window seal needs replacement? Thank you for your clear precise advice and your kindness to me! Sorry I sent question twice. I had difficullllty with posting question and especially posting photo.